# How to properly handle asynchronous error in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Below code explain two async code inside main async process . my problem was   "userController.insertUser" -- catched some error but that error not able to throw main catch

```
DataMiddleware.DataValidate(Object).then((middlewareSuccess) => {
            switch (true) {
              case ((tableName === "users") && (method === "CREATE")):


               userController.insertUser(Object).then(()=> {
                    ...
                }).catch((err) => {
                        return err
                })

                break;
              case ((tableName === "users") && (method === "BATCH")):

               userController.updateUser(Object).then(()=> {
                    ...
                }).catch((err) => {
                        return err
                })
                break;

            }

            }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log("main error",err)
            })
```

how to catch properly?

Comment: instead or `return err` try `throw err`, or remove the nested `catch` and let the last one handle them all

Comment: Thanks alex. I try throw err and remove nested catch also but main catch not able to catch

Comment: yeah of course my mistake, put `return` before `userController.insertUser` and `userController.updateUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to handle your nested promise errors.

**1) Catch it inside the nested promise and throw it to parent**

```js
const DataMiddleware = {
  DataValidate: sinon.fake.resolves("value")
};
const userController = {
  insertUser: sinon.fake.rejects("insertUser erroorr"),
  updateUser: sinon.fake.rejects("updateUser erroorr")
};
const tableName = "users",
  method = "CREATE";

DataMiddleware.DataValidate()
  .then(middlewareSuccess => {
    switch (true) {
      case tableName === "users" && method === "CREATE":
        return userController.insertUser()
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("nested catch handler " + err);
            throw err;
          });
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("main error " + err);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/5.0.1/sinon.js"></script>
```

**2) Return the promise and let parent handle any error that occurs**

```js
const DataMiddleware = {
  DataValidate: sinon.fake.resolves("value")
};
const userController = {
  insertUser: sinon.fake.rejects("insertUser erroorr"),
  updateUser: sinon.fake.rejects("updateUser erroorr")
};
const tableName = "users",
  method = "CREATE";

DataMiddleware.DataValidate()
  .then(middlewareSuccess => {
    switch (true) {
      case tableName === "users" && method === "CREATE":
        return userController.insertUser()
    }
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("main error " + err);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/5.0.1/sinon.js"></script>
```

The whole point here is promises chain. You return a new promise from another and the first `catch` handler still works.

Comment: Finally one question we use normal try and catch -- above your code
because i want parse my json 
 like this
try {
getObject = JSON.parse(getData);
DataMiddleware.DataValidate()
  .then(middlewareSuccess => {
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("main error " + err);
  });
}
catch(err) {

}

Comment: some times get error in JSON.parse like syntax error